# Is there a non-specialty paint that can be used on microwave interior?

Tags: paint, microwave-oven, refinishing

The interior of my older low-end microwave, where the rotating tray rollers contact, has worn through the original finish and become rusty.

There are specific microwave refinishing paints available, but they are costly enough to make getting a new microwave of similar quality a competitive option.

I want to repaint my current unit to make cleaning up spills and splatter easier.

I am considering standard 'rust paint' or generic 'appliance paint', but am concerned about possible fumes generated while cooking if the "incorrect" paint is used.

What type of paint is the 'microwave paint', and are there other more generally available paint types that could be safely used on a microwave interior?

Comment: I'm not certain on this, but a ceramic-style appliance paint should work.  Two things can't go in a microwave - moisture and metallic substances.  Whatever paint is used must cure completely leaving no moisture behind.

Comment: do you need paint there? an oil coat can stop further rusting.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I'm reaching out to rustoleum regarding their appliance and high heat paints to see what they say. I've been thinking along the same lines re: water/metal content but want confirmation.

Comment: @dandavis goal is easier cleaning so oil isn't a good solution in my case, I updated the question to clarify my goals. Appreciate the suggestion though, I hadn't really been looking at it from a rust treatment angle, got me considering rust converters also

Comment: @JPhi1618, if it's rusting doesn't that demonstrate that there's already metal there?

Comment: @isherwood, specially shaped metal designed to be there.  Curvy metal can focus the microwaves and cause hot spots, pointy metal can cause arcing.  I don't _think_ any touch up paint would contain metal, but if it did I'd really only worry about overheating and failure of the paint.  My main concern is moisture like when latex paint seems dry, but it really takes weeks for a full cure.